# How to inject a dynamic javascript in to asp .net core razor view

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, .net-core

Here is my code in razor view.

```
 @if (ViewBag.CurrentPageId != null)
    {
        var currentPage = wizard.Pages.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PageId == ViewBag.CurrentPageId);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentPage.JavaScript))
        {
            var a = currentPage.JavaScript.ToString();
            <script>alert(a)</script>
        }
    }
```

The script comes to me as currentPage.JavaScript. I want to add that script to my view. But above code gives the error: *a is not defined*

1. Is it possible to modify above code to work?
2. What is the best approach to  inject a dynamic javascript in to asp .net core razor view? Is it TagHelpers?

Please help.

Comment: to be clear `a is not defined` is an error which is produced by javascript?
If that this is the case than you didn't properly escape `a` to be "rendered" by razor. Just change it to: `<script>alert(@a)</script>`

Comment: Thanks. Yes it works. <script>alert(@a)</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for completeness I gonna express my comment as an elabortated anwer.

Starting a c# codeline in Razor with @ when using `if, using, for ...` (constructs that define code blocks) will not turn the whole block into interpreted c# razor.

As seen in the question it is absolutely possible to just start writing Markup inside such a block.

If you now want to use variables of the razor code to be rendered into the markup you still have to escape them by adding an `@` even though your are inside a "codeblock".

```
@if(...)
{
    (...)
    <script>alert(@a)</script>
    (...)
}
```